# Shouldn't all values of the covariance matrix under homoskedacity be zero?

Tags: regression, covariance, covariance-matrix

The following is an excerpt from Greene's Econometric Analysis, 8th Edition.

In homoskedacity, the covariance matrix has zero values for the expected errors of all pairs of observations $(i,e)$ whenever the observations are not the same (that is, i $i \neq e$).

[image]

Yet, in a regression, the expected value of all errors is zero:

[image]

So, shouldn't all values of the covariance matrix be zero as well? If $E[e_i | X] = 0 $, shouldn't $E[e_i   \cdot e_i| X] = 0 $ too?

Comment: Understanding "$\cdot$" to mean multiplication, because a square like "$e_i\cdot e_i$" can never be negative, if its expectation is $0$ then $e_i$ is itself almost surely zero.  That would scarcely be a useful model!  What, then, do you mean by "$\cdot$"??

Comment: I mean multiplication, because that's what I believe the author means: $\epsilon \epsilon$ would be $\epsilon \cdot \epsilon$. I might be wrong, though.

Comment: VAR[X] = E[X^2] - (E[X])^2... If E[X] = 0, VAR[X] = E[X^2] which is what you have here. So the diagonals should represent the variance of your residuals.

Comment: As others have pointed out $EX=0 \not\Rightarrow EX^2=0$. For a simple example consider a binary variable $X$ that takes on values $-1$ and $1$ with equal probability. The mean is then clearly $EX=(-1)*0.5+(1)*0.5=0$ while $EX^2 = (-1)^2*0.5 + (1)^2*0.5 = 1$

Answer (score 2):

Remember that the variance is defined as $Var(Z) = E[Z^2] - E[Z]^2$. In your example, if $E[e_i | X] = 0$ and $E[e_i^2 \space | X]$ = 0, then $Var(e_i | X) = 0$ too. That would mean that the errors are not random variables; they would always be 0.

Also, recall that $cov(Z, W) = E[ZW] - E[Z] * E[W]$. The terms in the covariance matrix all have the form $E[e_i e_j | X]$, so we can rewrite them in terms of covariance,
$$E[e_i e_j | X] = cov(e_i, e_j | X) + E[e_i|X] * E[e_j | X].$$

Because the conditional mean of $e_i$ and $e_j$ for any $i$ and $j$ is 0 (Assumption A.3 in your post), the product term I above is 0 and
$$E[e_i e_j | X] = cov(e_i, e_j | X).$$

We assume $e_i$ and $e_j$ are uncorrelated so $cov(e_i, e_j | X) = 0 = E[e_i e_j | X]$ when $i \neq j$.

When $i = j$, $cov(e_i, e_i | X)  = var(e_i | X) = \sigma^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Think in terms of what these expectations really mean and it will make intuitive sense that $\mathbb{E}[e_i|X]=0$ does not imply $\mathbb{E}[e_i^2|X]=0$. Given $\mathbb{E}[e_i|X]=0$, we have that $Var(e_1|X)=\mathbb{E}[e_i^2|X]$. So, it is not because a random variable has mean zero that the variance of this variable should necessarily be 0, right?.

Regarding the errors covariance matrix, because all errors are uncorrelated, all values off the principal diagonal (covariances) have value 0,.i.e., $\mathbb{E}[e_i e_j]=0,\forall i\neq j\ $ and, by homoskedasticity, all individual conditional variances of the errors $\mathbb{E}[e_i^2]$ have the same value, i.e., $\sigma^2$.

Answer (score 1):

In A4 Greene means the covariance matrix $\Omega_{ij}=E[\varepsilon_i,\varepsilon_j]=\sigma^2\delta_{ij}$. Diagonal values are $\sigma^2\ne 0$, only off-diagonal values are zero.